# If you control a site with ASP.NET MVC, can the viewers see the MVC code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, user-interface

...or is it safe to stick for example user data and passwords into the models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The viewers can't see the MVC code as what they see is the generated HTML not the aspx pages or code behind.

However, it's **never** a good idea to store user data and passwords in the models. This should be stored in a database and the passwords should **never** be stored in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

No, they can't see the MVC code but you still need to ensure that the site and server are secure whether the user credentials are stored in a database, the code, or in text files in a private store.

Answer (score 0):

User's won't see your server-side code. So yes, it is safe to put secret stuff in your models. But I guess you would be better off storing information like that in a database?

Comment: unless of course you're subject to a Sql Injection attack, then the hacker could dump the content of the database and get the codes, which he wouldn't otherwise have access to if they were in code (hypothetical of course)

Comment: @Pauli, well, you can't store an unbounded number of user passwords in code.  (Though even in the db, the passwords should of course be hashed.)

Comment: i think DarkLightA is referring to passwords that his application needs for authenticating towards other systems. whatever that needs to authenticate to his own application, their passwords should always be hashed (with a salt, very important) and can in that way be stored wherever.

Answer (score 0):

The user can never see that is executing on the server unless you explicitly write it out through ie. the `Html helper`.